# RandomSample Bug?

Tags: bugs, random

[image: Screen Shot of my Mathematica Commands]

I was using RandomSample with very skewed weights. I am asking for a random sample of 6 numbers 1 through 100 without replacement. In the screen shown, the weights for 1 through 6 are 100 000, with all others less then 1; hence, the RandomSample should return numbers 1 through 6 is a random order very very often. But it does not.

I have copied and pasted the commands shown.

Am I missing something? Or am I misunderstanding the RandomSample function? Or is this actually a bug?

Comment: Please *do not* post images as code. Read the formatting FAQ in the Help section, and post actual code.

Answer (score 4):

Definitely something interesting going on here.

```
c[x_] := Count[Table[RandomSample[{100000, 0, 1} -> {1, 2, 3}, 1], {x}], {3}]

DiscretePlot[c[x]/x, {x, 10, 400}]
```

[image]

Note that changing the zero weight to something greater than zero seems to give the expected behavior. Some experimentation seems to suggest that adding a zero weight in the presence of weights with large difference in scale causes other weights to be treated as equal.

I also notice that even when the weights are in the same ballpark odd stuff happens when we cross the 249 to 250 replication mark.

```
c2[x_] := Count[Table[RandomSample[{2, 0, 1, 2} -> {1, 2, 3, 4}, 1], {x}], {3}]
DiscretePlot[c[x]/x, {x, 10, 400}]
```

[image]

Comment: It is clearly documented "The weights must be *positive*...", emphasis mine.

Comment: The threshold of 250 is likely due to auto-compilation in `Table` (which kicks in at precisely 250).

Comment: [This](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/43385/12) would explain why weights can't be zero, but if it's really so by design, `RandomSample` should give a warning, the same as it warns about negative weights.

Comment: The weird behaviour at 250 is only with RandomSample, not RandomChoice, and only with integer weights, not with floating point weights.

Comment: @Szabolcs I suspected auto-compilation as well.